# customvalidator can't find controltovalidate

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator, createuserwizard

I'm having a problem finding a `TextBox` inside `CreateUserWizard` which is inside a `ContentPlaceholder`.

I have a `CustomValidator` for this textbox.  When I put the `CustomValidator` outside `CreateUserWizard` it says `cannot find controltovalidate control id CaptchaValue`

Here is a row inside my `CreateUserWizard`

```
<CreateUserWizard>
  <tr>     
    <td align="left">
      <asp:TextBox ID="CaptchaValue" runat="server" CssClass="texty"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
  </tr>
</CreateUserWizard>
```

and I have a `CustomValidator` outside `CreateUserWizard`:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CaptchaValue" 
                     ErrorMessage="Image value must match"
                     ValidationGroup="CreateUserWizard1" EnableClientScript="False">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place the CustomValidator inside the CreateUserWizard. The CustomValidator can't find the control with ID CaptchaValue because its in a different [INamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.inamingcontainer.aspx).